# XAML: How to bind element to Property the name of is dynamic, can have different name in different places

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I create a custom UserControl which have a ListControl.

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <simple:TrackItem />                          
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ItemsSource}"/>
</UserControl>
```

I also create a DependencyProperty in this custom UserControl and bind ListControl's ItemsSource to this DependencyProperty.

```
public partial class TracksList : UserControl
    {
        public TracksList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(TracksList), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable) GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

    }
```

I override the ItemTemplate of ItemsControl. This ItemTemplate have two TextBlock elements, so this TextBlocks needs the names of item DataType to bind theirs Text values to Properties.

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding "????????"}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding "????????"}"/>
```

Instead of "???????" I want to set the name of this Property dynamically - by custom string Property in custom UserControl.

[this is not working code, I remove unneeded parts to make it more readable]

Comment: Could you add a bit more details on what you intend to bind?  Also little more code on what's there in the item template etc

Comment: The IEnumerable data type it o bit to vague, and as a result, it is hard to get a specific position from it. Can you tell use the datatypes that you will bind to "ItemsSource"?

Comment: Do you want to display *every* property of each item in `ItemsSource`? Or just some properties? How will your code *decide* which properties to display?

Comment: Look, for example, if you declare xaml binding you write {Binding PropertyName}. But, instead of property name, i want to bind to property, that contains this propertyName. The same example exists in Devexpress framework [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10975). I want to say the FieldName, but not Field.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple multi-value converter:

```
public class NamedPropertyValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var sourceObj = values[0];
        var propName = values[1].ToString();

        var propInfo = sourceObj.GetType().GetProperty(propName);

        return propInfo.GetValue(sourceObj);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Example XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NamedPropertyValueConverter x:Key="NamedPropertyValue" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Foo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NamedPropertyValue}">
                    <Binding />
                    <Binding Path="PropertyNameProp" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And here's a simple viewmodel that I tested that with:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Foo Property
    private String _foo = "Initial value of Foo";
    public String Foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _foo)
            {
                _foo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PropertyNameProp));
                //  This works too, but all properties will be requeried.
                //  In some cases that may be too expensive. 
                //OnPropertyChanged(null);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion Foo Property

    #region PropertyNameProp Property
    private String _propertyNameProp = "Foo";
    public String PropertyNameProp
    {
        get { return _propertyNameProp; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _propertyNameProp)
            {
                _propertyNameProp = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion PropertyNameProp Property
}
```

Note that `Foo` must call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PropertyNameProp))` when its value changes. Otherwise, the `Binding` will not know that anything changed and will not update, because the `Binding` does not know that `Foo` exists.

You'd need to rethink things a bit if you want to implement `ConvertBack` for this converter, but you don't need that if you're putting the values in `TextBlock`s.